# Imported a library to an IntelliJ project, can't access it through code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working with the normal distribution so I need a library like Apache Math Commons. I try to download it using the following link (do I need both binary and source files?): http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi

I then try to import it into my project by File -> Project Structure -> + -> Add Library then hit Apply and OK. But when I try to instantiate a NormalDistribution object I get 'Cannot resolve symbol 'NormalDistribution'', even though this class is in the file.

(Apologies for the noob question)

Answer (score 0):

For adding new lib to your project follow these

1.Right click on your project -> open module settings - > module - > dependencies - > in right up corner there is + button -> click on that-> select jar or directory option
2. From here you can select required jar